# recovery mode works but cant select option galaxy i9000

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, rom

I am trying to update my rom and install carbon-rom. i have put the zip on the sdcard rebooted into recovery mode by pressing vol up +home +power.

I can enter recovery mode. when i do i see for options but can not select any of them. At the bottom of the screen in yellow writing it says "manual mode".

I have looked into it and thinking that the recovery is locked? Or am i just not pressing the right button to select the option?

I do not have odin or cwm installed, is this required? my phone is uk bought when first released and never updated.